# Pound signs saving as question marks in my SQL database

Tags: python, mysql, utf

I've searched on this for a while but none seem to be quite relevant enough.

Basically, I have a csv file that is extracted from a program. I wrote a quick python program to convert the csv file to an sql file so I can import it into the database. I then import the .sql file using the windows command prompt to my remote MySQL server.

I have some pound signs (£) in some of the fields in my database. In the csv file, they are showing as £, in the resulting sql file (after conversion) they are showing as \£ because of my use of re.escape - I'm actually thinking this may be the reason (The python code that writes this to the file is: 
for row in csvReader:
    ...other stuff...
    sqlfile.write(re.escape(row[6])).

After the file is imported, I view the tables and the pound signs are now showing as ? in the tables, and when the contents is shown on the website using php to query.
The database Server connection collation is utf8_general_ci and I'm connecting to the remote server with thiscommand:
mysql --host=HOST --user=USER --password=PASS --default-character-set=utf8 DATABASENAME < filetoimport.sql

Changing the character encoding on firefox made no difference, as expected - whatever is happening seems to be when the sql dump is imported.

Being honest, I'm not really completely sure I understand how the whole character set things work, I've never really had to try and fix a problem like this before so I'm not really sure what else to try. Any help or even a point in the right direction to search, as my searches so far doesn't seem to be helping me :(

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using `re.escape` to escape things you're writing to SQL? `re.escape` is for escaping things being put into regular expressions, not SQL.

Comment: Someone suggested it to me to solve a problem that a lot of characters I was trying to use in a TEXT type field. " ' ; etc, were all breaking it.

Comment: The chars might be imported into the db correctly. Try to confirm that first. I'm thinking perhaps its the viewing mechanism (php/firefox) which is still in 7bit ascii (displaying the ?'s), and not the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysql's escape function.  Mysqldb is something like:

```
conn.escape_string()
```

Comment: Thank you, I've switched everything over to python now using mysqldb (instead of using the mysql command line interface to insert the new data) and with a little fiddling, it's showing perfectly now!